# How to check google access token date expires or not

Tags: javascript, meteor, google-oauth, momentjs

I want to check whether the accesstoken in my db is expired or not.

I'm working with meteor framework and when I login it is saving in my db as following

```
 "expiresAt" : ISODate("2015-03-24T07:03:41.000Z"),
```

I'm trying to check this date is expired or not by using the following methods

```
   var dd=new Date(google.expiresAt).getTime();
    if(dd < Date.now()){
      var r = HTTP.post("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token",{
                params: {
                  'client_id': googleConf.clientId,
                  'client_secret': googleConf.secret,
                  'refresh_token': google.refreshToken,
                  'grant_type': 'refresh_token'
                }
              });
    }
    var expiry=new Date((new Date) + r.data.expires_in * 1000);
```

and updating like this, those code is not working

tried this too

```
if (google.expiresAt < +(new Date()).toISOString() + 10 * 1000) {
  var r = HTTP.post("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token",{
            params: {
              'client_id': googleConf.clientId,
              'client_secret': googleConf.secret,
              'refresh_token': google.refreshToken,
              'grant_type': 'refresh_token'
            }
          });
}
var expiry=new Date((new Date) + r.data.expires_in * 1000);
```

Both of these are not working, how exactly to know whether the date is expired or not

Comment: Access tokens expire after an hour.  Log when you got it and if its been more then an hour get a new one.

Comment: @DaImTo bad move. The access token always comes with an expires value which is what you should use, rather than assume 1 hour. Eg. {
  "access_token":"1/fFBGRNJru1FQd44AzqT3Zg",
  "expires_in":3920,
  "token_type":"Bearer",
}

Comment: I always let the client lib handle it much easier

Comment: @noName can you expand on "not working". What is the expected result vs. actual result?

Comment: although my token expires, the loop is not executing, the checking is not working correct

Comment: It would be good to get some console logs of the variables to see what is being compared with what. Having said that, you could always simply try to use the token and catch the resulting 401 exception. Your app should be catching 401's anyway, so there shouldn't be any new code to write. One more question, where is the ""expiresAt" value coming from for you to save it?